# Why am I sending empty download photo requests?

Tags: photos

A contact is receiving download photo notifications I'm not actually sending that are empty after they are clicked. Whats causing this? Is my phone spamming some body?

Comment: What kind of phone is your friend using? Are they receiving these notifications from a particular app?

Comment: The messages are coming from an Iphone 6 to an android in the normal message income. They look the same as a normal photo download but, are empty.